# How can i customize twilio flex ui account menu?

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

I would like to customize the flex ui account menu. My use case is: i want to filter the activities (status) displayed for a worker based on some attribute in the worker attributes.

[twilio flex ui account menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnIal.png)

In the image example we can see the opened menu with my activities, as it is, all the activities are displayed for all the workers.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a couple of ways to achieve this as Twilio doesn't provide additional functionality to customize those activity options in that dropdown currently.

- You can try to create your custom component and replace the `user-controls` component in MainHeader: [https://assets.flex.twilio.com/docs/releases/flex-ui/1.33.0/MainHeader.html#:~:text=Mute%20button-,user%2Dcontrols,-React%20component](https://assets.flex.twilio.com/docs/releases/flex-ui/1.33.0/MainHeader.html#:%7E:text=Mute%20button-,user%2Dcontrols,-React%20component). Keep in mind that you have to get those activities, display them, and also emit the necessary events on this one.
- You can modify CSS with attribute selectors: if you inspect the HTML, you will recognize some attributes that you can use to find those elements. Take a look at this screenshot:[image: ss of Twilio user-controls component when clicked]
  So, you can have a script to modify CSS in one of your components. For example, to hide the `Outbound Calls` so that it cannot be selected manually, you can do something like this:

  ```
  const oCallsElement = document.querySelector<HTMLElement>(
      "button[data-test='activity-Outbound Calls']"
    );
  if (oCallsElement) oCallsElement.style.display = 'none';
  ```

*One thing to keep in mind though, there might be other activity selection menus depending on your Flex configuration. For example, I have two another ones, one on `NoTaskCanvas` and the other one is on `Team View`, appears when a user click on one of the agent names. Make sure to edit them/remove them to have a consistent functionality.*

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I haven't done too much with Flex, but here's what I would do/where I would start:

You can listen for a worker to be selected in the supervisor view using the [Actions Framework](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/ui/actions) [`SelectWorkerInSupervisor`](https://assets.flex.twilio.com/docs/releases/flex-ui/1.27.0/Actions.html#.SelectWorkerInSupervisor)[action](https://assets.flex.twilio.com/docs/releases/flex-ui/1.27.0/Actions.html#.SelectWorkerInSupervisor) (you can listen to `beforeSelectWorkerInSupervisor` or `afterSelectWorkerInSupervisor`.)

Re. filtering: I think you can affect the state in redux based on the worker you currently have selected. This [filtering plugin](https://github.com/twilio-professional-services/plugin-queues-view-filters) may be of interest to you, as well as [this docs page on filtering](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/ui/team-view-filters) and [components docs page](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/ui/components)

Also, here's the [Overview of Flex UI programmability options](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/ui/overview-of-flex-ui-programmability-options).

Let me know if this helps at all!

Comment: Hello @lizziepika, the ideia here was to customize the dropdown menu in the worker view. I still could not find how to do this in the docs.

Comment: which dropdown menu?

Comment: The dropdown menu used to select the worker activity.

Comment: @lucassimonini have you figured this out? I'm trying to modify I believe the same component. It seems that it's called 'user-controls' under MainHeader component.

Comment: @lizziepika when you click on the user profile (profile pic and user name) on top right (https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/ui/components#mainheader) an activity modal opens up where you can select user activity such as Available, Unavailable, etc.